# APK Size, Twilio, Splits and architectures compatibility

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, twilio, build.gradle

Which architectures should be placed in splits.abi build.gradle?
I'm compiling using only "armeabi-v7a" because using all native libraries for all architectures generates a very large APK.
I am using Proguard. But I am afraid that using only "armeabi-v7a" can bring a lot of compatibility problems.

```
splits {
       ...
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi-v7a"
            universalApk false
        }
}
```

I'm using '[com.twilio:client-android:1.2.14](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/changelog#1214-june-16-2016)' and '[com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.8.1](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/changelogs/android#ip-messaging-android-081-june-29-2016)' on my android proyect.

For each architecture I'm getting 3 .so files inside my lib/ folder: libclient.so, libtwilio-rtd-native.so and libtwilio_common_android_so. Aprox, 9MB foreach architecture = 36MB.

The question is: what about users with devices and other architectures?

Comment: I believe you can have 3 apks to cover all architectures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately this comes down to your own needs. We provide the SDK for  `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, and `x86-64`. You decide which architectures you want to compile for, each with pros (smaller APK size) and cons (loss of potential installs) is up to you.

Generally speaking, `armeabi` is for older devices (<2010), `armeabi-v7a` for (2010-2014), and `arm64-v8a` (2015+). And `x86*` is a growing segment.

You can also consider splitting your APK, if the size is problematic:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html